# Setting secure_cookie for a response through Nginx

Tags: cookies, nginx, tornado

I have a Tornado instance running behind a Nginx, and when a GET request hits Nginx first, it will direct the request to a handler in Tornado by using:

```
proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080;
proxy_redirect          off;
```

then inside the corresponding handler in Tornado:

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, collection, item):
        tag = self.get_argument('tag')
        self.set_secure_cookie('tag', tag, expires_days=None, httponly=True, secure=True)
        self.set_header('X-Accel-Redirect', ''.join(('/blah/blah/', collection, '/', item, '/tag.html')))
        self.finish()
```

which basically re-direct the request back to Nginx and ask it to serve a static html page. However, as shown above, I want to set a secure cookie before the re-direction. Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a secure cookie is just handled differently inside tornado.web. Internally it just calls `set_cookie`with an encrypted value.

```
def set_secure_cookie(self, name, value, expires_days=30, **kwargs):
    self.set_cookie(name, self.create_signed_value(name, value),
                    expires_days=expires_days, **kwargs)
```

According to the [nginx Documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) nginx will just forward the Set-Cookie HTTP header to the browser when using XSendfile/X-Accel.

Comment: The "redirect" is just handled by nginx. The browser will never see any difference between the static request beeing handled by nginx or tornado.

Comment: FYI- Not all browsers will honor cookies on a redirect.  Firefox, IE, Chrome do , but Safari will not.

Comment: The browser will not get a redirect answer or even an HTTP 3xx code. The redirect is just handled by nginx internally. Nginx sends the static file just as tornado would do it. The browser will get an HTTP 200 containing the static data, handled by nginx. Tornado decides on sending _what_ static data but nginx _does_ send the data because it is a much faster and more reliable static file server than tornado.